# Does next test's page requires a new layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I aim to make a quiz application for android. I am planning that the user pushes next button and the quiz goes to next question (Like in the image) . The question count is not specified. So should i use a new layout for each question ?

[image: Something like that]

Comment: no load each question in same layout

Comment: Use the same layout and just change the values of each view every time the next button is clicked @nsarchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would try to reuse same layout with new values.